# MSMQ. Who can create a local queue (permissions required)?

Tags: msmq

A simple question that I can't find an answer to:

**Which user and what permissions are required to create a local queue using MSMQ?**

I am using C# to call:

```
MessageQueue.Create(queuePath, transactional);
```

I got an error once saying:

```
Access to Message Queuing system is denied.
```

I have not been able to reproduce this error again. I have tried using limited accounts such as 'Guest' but I have not been able to reproduce this error.

Comment: Typically users with Admin Permissions are allowed to create queues. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753761(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Thanks tx fun. I believe that page is referencing setting permissions on an existing queue. I'm having trouble finding information on who can create a queue (rather than set permissions on an existing queue). What I am seeing is that anyone can create a queue (which is ok in my situation, but I want to be sure).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have found is that anyone can create a queue using:

```
 MessageQueue.Create
```

My error was that I was getting

```
Access to Message Queuing system is denied.
```

was because I was trying to set permissions on the queue straight after creating it using code similar to this (this is what was causing the error):

```
queue.SetPermissions(user, MessageQueueAccessRights.WriteMessage, AccessControlEntryType.Allow);
```